# How to use class declarations using jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to make a mod for Minecraft using Forge and JRuby. I want to use Ruby to write mods, but I need use class declarations for Forge to accept it as a mod.

```
@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
```

I tried write this like a function, but it doesn't work. I see no errors, but Forge doesn't recognize then.

```
Mod(modid = MyMod.modid, version = MyMod.version)
```

How do I write this in Ruby? If i write this part in Java and the rest in Ruby, it works, but I would prefer for it to all be in Ruby.

Edited:
This is the correct way to create a mod using java:

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {

    }
}
```

My code in ruby:

```
require 'java'

import 'cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod'
import 'cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry'
import 'net.minecraft.init.Blocks'
import 'net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs'
import 'net.minecraft.block.material.Material'

class MyMod
    modid = "examplemod2";
    version = "1.0";

    def init(event)

    end
end
```

Comment: Can you write the equivalent Java code for what you are attempting in Ruby?

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: Does that not give you what you expect?

Comment: I pasted the wrong code, sorry.

Comment: Does it work with the `java_annotation`?

Comment: No the forge does not recognize the mod. i'm thinking, if i create a class in java and extend using ruby and changing the variable values MODID and version maybe it's work but i dont know how to make the last part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like these are annotations, so take a look at [JRuby's reference on them](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRuby-Reference#java_annotation).

It might end up looking something like:

```
java_annotation('Mod(modid="MyModID", name="MyModName")')
class MyMod
  # ... mod stuff
end
```